# Create a timestamp with time zone in PostgreSQL from Liquibase XML

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I have a Liquibase migration XML file which creates columns with the `datetime` type.

```
<createTable tableName="foo">
    <column name="bar" type="datetime"/>
</createTable>
```

I realized to my consternation today that these are being created without a timezone (`timestamp without time zone` in PostgreSQL) and there doesn't seem to be any Liquibase type that you can use that will give you a `timestamp with time zone`. Is there any way to deal with this beyond having an `<sql>` block that alters the table like so after initially creating the table:

```
<sql>
alter table foo alter column bar type timestamp with time zone;
</sql>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use native types in the `createTable` tag: `type="timestamptz"` - `datetime` is a non-standard type as well.

Comment: This worked! If you make it an answer I can accept it.

Comment: I'm using jhipster, which uses liquibase, and did a little test by creating a simple project with a single entity, containing a `ZonedDateTime` `LocalDateTime` `Instant` to see how these fields are mapped to their respective columns. Well, they are all mapped to a "datetime" column. Should we assume that this behaviour is wrong, or using datetime is ok for all the mentioned types?

Comment: If it's not storing a time zone, then it's wrong for ZonedDateTime and Instant. It's correct for LocalDateTime.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TL;DR: use `timestamp with time zone`:

```
<column name="bar" type="timestamp with time zone"/>
```

Liquibase `datetime` will be automatically converted to the target database's timestamp type, but it is not possible to specify a time zone.

Liquibase will accept `timestamp with time zone` and pass it as a native type (no conversion), but as it is SQL standard type, it will be accepted by any standard database anyway (including PostgreSQL).

`timestamptz` is PostgreSQL-specific abbreviation for the same data type. It is not portable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, which was provided in a comment by https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name, is to use the `timestamptz` native PostgreSQL type:

```
<createTable tableName="foo">
    <column name="bar" type="timestamptz"/>
</createTable>
```